# What's the day today?

Tags: phrases, expressions

When we ask the day of the week, can we use "What's the day today?" instead of "What day is it today?" Is it a common phrase?

Comment: Ngram viewer finds only *What day is today?*; your options are strange for them!

Comment: Probably the easiest way to get a “day-of-the-week” answer is to take your best guess at it and ask, “Is today Thursday?”

Comment: And when you get old and decrepit, you will also ask, "and where am I?"

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it.  To be unambiguous one must ask something like "What day of the week is it today", and most people go for something shorter.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a common phrase and it's likely to make people wonder what you meant. They might wonder if today was a holiday or someone's birthday or something like that. They would not think you were asking what day of the week it is.

Comment: I've probably heard this expression as often as 'What day is it today?' (with the same meaning) (but both are fairly rare, as most people don't need to ask it. That said, there are over half a million Google hits for the expression.) As tchrist has said, 'We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.'

Answer (score 1):

"What's the day today?" is correct English. It is a little stilted, but I have heard children ask the question exactly that way.